# Json stringify issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
var User = new Object();

        User.Id = 0;
        User.Username = $("#username").val();
        User.Password = $("#password").val();

        var jsonText = JSON.stringify(User);


        jsonText = "{\"User\" : " + JSON.stringify(User) + "}";
        alert(jsonText);

 $.ajax({
            url: '/Main/Submit/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonText,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                // get the result and do some magic with it
                var message = data.Message;
                $("#resultMessage").html(message);
            }
        });


public ActionResult Submit(User User)
           {
           }
```

In the MVC function User entity does not contain the values.

Comment: What does the signature of the MVC method  look like please?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to stringify your object into a JSON string, you can simply send the object. If `User` is your parameter name, the following should work (I changed some of the syntax to simplify it a bit).

```
var User = {
    Id: 0,
    Username:  $("#username").val(),
    Password: $("#password").val()
};

$.post('<%= Url.Action("Submit", "Main") %>', { User: User }, function (data) {
    // get the result and do some magic with it
    var message = data.Message;
    $("#resultMessage").html(message);
});
```

Comment: Well, remember that MVC works by using reflection to bind properties. The property names on your User object must exactly be `Id`, `Username`, and `Password`. Is your controller action even being hit?

Comment: Yes the controller action is being hit but the variable values are null. Name of the parameters are exactly the same with case.

Comment: @sly_Chandan: Then there's probably a data type or content type issue. Whenever I do jQuery AJAX with MVC, I keep it really simple and use the `$.get()` and `$.post()` shortcuts. I updated my answer. Also note that I removed the hard-coded action route -- you should let MVC do that work for you.